# Problem between auto-pst-pdf and \ifPDFTex

Tags: xetex, auto-pst-pdf

I would like to build a document which can compile with LaTex, pdfLaTeX or xeLateX.

But on the code below you can see that it doesn't compile with LaTeX : the trouble seems to come from the \ifPDFTeX because with the \ifpdf from the ifpdf package there is no problem.
No problem with xelatex and pdflatex.

The trouble is with auto-pst-pdf and \ifPDFTeX

What's wrong ???

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{iftex}

\ifXeTeX
  \usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
  \usepackage{xunicode} %à charger après fontspec
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %pour linux
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %lettres accentuées %problème de flou en .pdf mais pas avec cm-super
\fi

%This does not work :
\ifXeTeX\else\ifPDFTeX\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}\fi\fi

%This works :
%\usepackage{ifpdf}
%\ifXeTeX\else\ifpdf\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}\fi\fi

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

Essai

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,4)
\psline(0,0)(4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And the log :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

<recently read> \fi 

l.14 ...\else\ifPDFTeX\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}\fi
                                                  \fi
! Extra \fi.
l.14 ...se\ifPDFTeX\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}\fi\fi
```

**EDIT 1 : new problem with this example :**

When compiling with pdflatex, some material is putted on a second page and the word "essai" comes two times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{iftex,ifpdf}

\ifXeTeX
  \usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

%Some material put on a 2nde page  :
\ifpdf\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}\fi

%Works normalty with this :
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

Essai

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,4)
\psline(0,0)(4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2 : And same problem here when not using ifpdf :**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%without this no problem ...
\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
\else
\pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
\pdftrue
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

Essai

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,4)
\psline(0,0)(4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \ifpdf tests the output mode, `\ifPDFtex` the engine, so the second is true for pdflatex and latex.

Comment: unrelated but do you need xunicode? one of the benefits of the new tuenc support is that it greatly reduces the number of packages that get pulled in (xunicode being one of them)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Thank you. I understand now. Il will use ifpdf.
But i have a new problem. I will edit the code above to post a example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I've copy/paste some code found to try xelatex ... and tuenc was give to me in another post (to use cm-unicode).
I will try without xunicode.
Another question : is the package "unicode-math" needed anymore with 'tuenc' or not ?

Comment: @Oli Your definition of `\ifpdf` is wrong. What Ulrike suggested is `\usepackage{ifpdf}`, which provides the correct `\ifpdf` conditional.

Comment: @egreg Yes so I made the first edit **with \usepackage{iftex,ifpdf}** but in this example, I have the same problem too : some text and the pspicture is puted on the second page. I don't understand why ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but \usepackage{geometry} solves the problem.
This example now works with LaTeX and pdfLaTeX too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%solution to the problem : 
\usepackage{geometry}

%\ifpdf %not necessary with geometry
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\fi

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

Essai

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,4)
\psline(0,0)(4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's because `geometry` loads `ifpdf` by itself and for some reason the error is not raised. But I wouldn't call this a solution.

Comment: Yes but I loaded ifpdf too, and before geometry ... So "geometry" really do something else.

Answer (score 1):

This works for `xelatex`, `pdflatex` and `latex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{iftex,ifpdf}

\ifXeTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \typeout{==== pdflatex ===}%
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
  \else
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
    \pagestyle{empty}
  \fi
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %pour linux
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

    Essai

    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,4)
    \psline(0,0)(4,4)
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It works with LaTeX and XeLaTeX but it doesn't work with PdfLaTeX. I've put all the files here : http://ovh.to/MkwJ3ac. Any ideas ?

Comment: Links doesn't work.
Here is the pdf output : http://www.cjoint.com/c/FJFk2U3HNc3
And the log : http://www.cjoint.com/c/FJFk3LsYhV3

Comment: The `\pagestyle{empty}` was missing, see edited answer

Comment: Thank's for your answer.
But always a problem : the word 'essai' is printed two times.
Pdf : http://www.cjoint.com/c/FJFtlz06FX3
Log : http://www.cjoint.com/c/FJFtl7xtiY3

Comment: Ah, I see. We also need for that case the `auto-pst-pdf`. See edited answer.

Comment: Now it works with xelatex and pdflatex but not with latex ...
Output : ! Extra \fi.
l.13   \fi

Comment: No idea for this strange behavior ?
With the 2nd \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} it doesn't work with LaTeX (I think it is normal because auto-pst-pdf is for PdfLaTeX and not LaTeX) ... But without the 2nd \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}it doesn't work with PdfLaTeX : this is strange because when compiling with pdflatex, this "else" part sould'nt be read by pdflatex !

Comment: There is a general problem with running `latex`. It is diffficult to know if it is started by the user or by the package `auto-pst-pdf` in the background. Both need a different preamble.

Comment: OK I used pdflatex and now I try to use xelatex.
So it doesn't matter : I don't use often latex.
I will keep the version which works with pdflatex and xelatex
Thank's a lot.

Comment: But by adding \usepackage{geometry} after \usepackage{iftex,ifpdf} it works with latex, padflatex and xelatex.
So this package adds something usefull ...

Comment: I'll have a look at weekend ...